# Solve the functional equation $f (2x)=f (x)\cos x$

Tags: functions, functional-equations, recursion

Find all $f: \mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R $ 
such that $f $ is a continuous  function at $0$ and satisfies 
$$\;\forall \:x \in \mathbb R,\; f\left(2x\right) = f\left(x\right)\cos x $$

My try: I just found the $f (x)$ is periodic,  i.e.
$f (2\pi / 2)= f (\pi/2) \cos (\pi /2) $

And$ f (\pi)=f (3\pi)$ ... and so on,
Best I came up with is
$$f (2^n x) = f (x) \cos (x) \cos (2x) ... \cos (2^{n-1} x)$$

Comment: By inspection $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 1$ is one solution.

Comment: There are some rather serious problems with this post, so you should consider using the [edit] to improve it. The tags aren't relevant, and you should include your own thoughts and efforts in this problem: What context did you find this in? What techniques are you aware of? What have you tried? You may also find it helpful to include an English translation of the question.

Comment: If English is not your first language, I would suggest using the `translation-request` tag. Hopefully, one of our users proficient in both languages will be able to provide an adequate translation.

Comment: I did fix the issues, I am just reading this from original book in Arabic, and then I found a similar question in French. I am just practicing some problems in Analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$f(x) = f\left(\dfrac{x}2\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{x}2\right) = f\left(\dfrac{x}4\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{x}4\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{x}2\right)$$
Hence, we have
$$f(x) = f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^{n}}\right) \prod_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\dfrac{x}{2^k}\right) = \dfrac1{2^n} f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n} \right)}$$
Hence, we have that
$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{2^n} f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right) \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right) \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{2^n} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)} = \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \lim_{n \to \infty} f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)$$
If we assume that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ exists at the origin, we then have that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right) = c$$
from which we obtain that
$$f(x) = c\cdot \dfrac{\sin(x)}x$$

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the comment by @JimmyK4542, on possible answer is $\;f\left(x\right) := \dfrac{\sin x}x\,$ for all $\,x\neq 0,\,$ so that
$$
f\left(2x\right) = \dfrac{\sin 2x}{2x} = \dfrac{2\sin x\cos x}{2x} = 
\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\,\cos x =f\left(x\right)\cos x
$$

---

Alternatively, you can find solution in terms of Taylor series, assuming $\,f\,$ is sufficiently smooth.

Let $\;f\left(x\right) = \sum a_n\,x^n,\,$ and $\;f\left(2x\right) = \sum a_n\,\left(2x\right)^n = \sum 2^na_n\,x^n.\,$
Recall $\displaystyle\,\cos x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(2n\right)!}\,x^{2n},\,$ then

\begin{align}
f\left(2x\right) &= f\left(x\right)\cos x
&\iff&&
\sum 2^na_n\,x^n & = \left(\sum_{} a_n\,x^n\right) \left(\sum_{} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(2n\right)!}\,x^{2n}\right)
\end{align}
or, more explicitly,

\begin{align}
a_0 + 2a_1\,x + 2^2a_2\,x^2 + 2^3a_3\,x^3 + 2^4a_4\,x^4 + 2^5a_5\,x^5 + \ldots
=
\Big(a_0 + a_1\,x + a_2\,x^2 + a_3\,x^3 + a_4\,x^4 + a_5\,x^5 + \ldots\Big) \cdot \Big( 1 - \dfrac{1}{2!}x^2 + \dfrac{1}{4!}x^4 - \dfrac{1}{6!}x^6 + \dfrac{1}{8!}x^8 - \ldots\Big)
\end{align}

Collecting coefficients in front of powers of $\,x\,$ we get

\begin{align}
a_0 &= a_0 \cdot 1 &\implies&& a_0&=\alpha \;\text{ – free parameter}\\
2a_1 &= a_1 \cdot 1 &\implies&& a_1 &= 0\\
2^2a_2 &= a_2 \cdot 1 +a_0\cdot \dfrac{-1}{2!}
  &\implies && a_2 &= \dfrac{1}{2^2-1}\left(\dfrac{-1}{2!}\right)a_0\\
  &&&&&=\dfrac{1}{3!}\,a_0\\
2^3a_3 &= a_3 \cdot 1 +a_1\cdot \dfrac{-1}{2!}
  &\implies && a_3 &= \dfrac{1}{2^3-1}\cdot\dfrac{-1}{2!}\,a_1 =0\\
2^4a_4 &= a_4 \cdot 1 +a_2\cdot \dfrac{-1}{2!} +a_0\cdot \dfrac{1}{4!}
 &\implies&&a_4&=\frac1{2^4-1}\left(\frac{-1}{2!}\,a_2+\frac1{4!}\,a_0\right)\\
% &&&&&=\frac{1}{2^4-1}\left(\dfrac{-1}{2!}\cdot\dfrac{1}{3!}  + \dfrac{1}{4!}\right)a_0\\
% &&&&&=\dfrac{2^2}{\left(2^2-1\right)\left(2^4-1\right)}a_0\\
  &&&&&=\dfrac{1}{5!}\,a_0\\
2^5a_5 &= a_5 \cdot 1 +a_2\cdot \dfrac{-1}{2!} +a_0\cdot \dfrac{1}{4!}
  &\implies &&a_5 & = 0\\
2^6a_6 &=
  a_6\cdot1 +a_4\cdot\dfrac{-1}{2!} +a_2\cdot\dfrac1{4!} +a_0\cdot\dfrac{-1}{6!}
  &\implies &&a_6 & = \dfrac{1}{2^6-1}
  \left(
    a_4\cdot\dfrac{-1}{2!} +a_2\cdot\dfrac1{4!} +a_0\cdot\dfrac{-1}{2!}
  \right)\\
  &&&&&=\dfrac{-1}{7!}\,a_0\\
2^7a_7 &= a_7 \cdot 1 +a_2\cdot \dfrac{-1}{2!} +a_0\cdot \dfrac{1}{4!}
  &\implies &&a_7 & = 0\\
&&\cdots
\end{align}
Generalizing formulas above we get
\begin{align}
a_n = 
\begin{cases}
0,& n = 2k+1,& k\in\mathbb R\\
\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^\frac{n}{2}}{\left(n+1\right)!},& n = 2k,& k\in\mathbb R
\end{cases}
\end{align}
so that 
$$
f\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^k}{\left(2k+1\right)!} = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}
$$